# SwiftUI HealthKit Oxygen Saturation

Tags: swiftui, watchkit, healthkit

I've a question, it's possible via HealthKit in SwiftUi measure the Oxygen Saturation on the new apple watch serie 6 directly from sensor similar to heart rate? I've write this code where ask confirm to access but read the data from health and not from directly from sensor.

```
struct O2View: View {
    
    private var healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    
    @State private var value = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Text("O2")
                    .font(.system(size: 50))
                Spacer()
            }
            HStack{
                Text(value)
                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                    .font(.system(size: 70))
            }

        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(perform: start)
    }
    

    func start() {
        autorizeHealthKit()
        startOxygenRateQuery(quantityTypeIdentifier: .oxygenSaturation)
    }
    
    func autorizeHealthKit() {
        let healthKitTypes: Set = [
        HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.heartRate)!]

        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: healthKitTypes, read: healthKitTypes) { _, _ in }
    }
    
    private func startOxygenRateQuery(quantityTypeIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
        
        let devicePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: [HKDevice.local()])

        let updateHandler: (HKAnchoredObjectQuery, [HKSample]?, [HKDeletedObject]?, HKQueryAnchor?, Error?) -> Void = {
            query, samples, deletedObjects, queryAnchor, error in
            
        guard let samples = samples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
            return
        }
            
        self.process(samples, type: quantityTypeIdentifier)

        }
        
        let query = HKAnchoredObjectQuery(type: HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: quantityTypeIdentifier)!, predicate: devicePredicate, anchor: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, resultsHandler: updateHandler)
        
        query.updateHandler = updateHandler

        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
    
    private func process(_ samples: [HKQuantitySample], type: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) {
        var lastOxygenRate = ""
        for sample in samples {
            if type == .oxygenSaturation {
                lastOxygenRate = sample.quantity.description
            }
            
            self.value = lastOxygenRate
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks al lot in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution ?